# No input file specified. after login into magento admin pannel showing this error

Tags: magento

> No input file specified. after login into magento admin pannel showing
>   this error

**No input file specified.**

> please help me out of this..

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess issues on Magento in Godaddy Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152425/htaccess-issues-on-magento-in-godaddy-server)

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to root .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your magneto store running on Go Daddy Server......The Error usually comes up if you’re hosted by Go Daddy...

Follow these steps i.e given in this tutorial:-

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/error/no_input_file_specified